# Primary key choice with a multi-client database

Tags: database, database-design

Sorry if this has already been asked before, but I couldn't find something particular to this. Let's say I am making a multi-client database where everything is in the same schema, which contains two tables, a Clients table and a Deals table. Each client would get a client id, and each deal would have a unique deal_id (set to auto-increment) as well as a client id marking every deal. The question is, is it usually better to have the primary key be (client_id, deal_id), (deal_id, client_id) or just on deal_id. I will be using MySQL if that is relevant.

In favor of the first choice, almost every query will contain a "WHERE client_id = ..." section, and InnoDB can make use of the first part of the (client_id, deal_id) index even if it isn't searching for the deal_id, which would speed up performance. On the other hand, it might be a problem because we might often be inserting and selecting from different pages, which would decrease performance.

As for the second choice, this would remove the problem with the first choice, however, we would no longer have the additional optimization from being able to use the client_id part of the index even when we aren't querying the deal_id. The downside of this approach is that now both client_id and deal_id would be used in any additional indexes we created (and there would definitely be other indexes).

The last option is to just use deal_id and just create other indexes which would contain client_id. This would address the space problem of option two, but might have other drawbacks I'm unaware of.

I'm leaning towards option 3, but I was wondering if there were any best practices or things I didn't take into consideration.

Comment: The question you need to answer, for yourself as well as for us to be able to advise you properly, is which distinct columns in the Deal table will be used in the WHERE clause to SELECT one or more deals?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc. Most of the time, it will be client_id in conjunction with some combination deal_id, name, or phone number. However, this is only one table and there will be others in the database. It's a relatively limited number of probable indexes.

Comment: You are trying to optimize too much, too soon. Go with the simple PK (deal_id). You can always add multiple extra indexes later on, as needed, and the penalty is minimal. If you decide for a composite PK then you are opting for a complex, **dirty** model; such a complex model can be useful, but only in very special cases (yours isn't one).